# Take input from file and store them in diffrent variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, file, sh

I have a problem in which I want to take input from the file in shell script. I have stored the input in file row-wise like

```
input.txt (File)
filename
attribute name
value
```

This is the format of my file and I want to use them in my code to use them

```
test.js
X_CLOUD_ID
100
no
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
file_loop = "yes"
while [ "$file_loop" != "no" ]
do
    echo 'Enter the file name'
    read file
    attribute_loop = "yes"
    while [ "$attribute_loop" != "no" ]
    do
      echo 'Enter the attribute to change'
      read attribute 
      echo 'Enter value of the attribute'
      read value
      sed -i 's/'$attribute':.*/'$attribute':'$value'/' $file
      echo "Do you want to change in new attribute? yes/no"
      read attribute_loop
    done
    echo "Do you want to change in new file? yes/no"
    read file_loop
done
```

I want to take the input from the file and perform the task. Is it possible then please let me know?

Comment: First you might want to fix your script. Have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/. Once you resolved the problems in the script you should be able to call it with `yourScript.sh < yourFileContainingTheInput`.

Comment: So which part are you having problems with?

Comment: @EktaSahu : Your question is a bit blurry. Do you mean that instead of asking the user for input, the responses to the questions you are writing with `echo` should come from a file? In this case, it should be sufficient to feed your file into the stdin of your script, because `read` reads from stdin.

Comment: @user1934428 the code which has been shown here is the code which doing all the work manually i don't want to use any echo the thing which i am concerned with is the input form the file to the fields like filename,attribute and value. I hope now you visualize my question.

Comment: Well, then just remove the `echo` lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to read the values contained in `test.js` into separate variables in your script, you can save yourself a lot of grief and simply use `mapfile` or `readarray` (they are synonymous) to read each line of the file into a separate element of an array. The builtins read the input from `stdin` and you will want to include the `-t` option to suppress reading the `'\n'` at the end of each line as part of the input.

To read the line from your file `test.js` passed as the first argument (*positional parameter*) to your script, you need nothing more than:

```
readarray -t arr < "$1"
```

to read the lines of input into the indexed array `arr`. Adding a bit of validation, you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -r "$1" ] || {
    printf "error: insufficient input.\nusage: %s file\n" "${0##*/}" >&2
    exit 1;
}

declare -a arr

readarray -t arr < "$1" || {
    printf "error: failed to read array from file '%s'.\n" "$1" >&2
    exit 1;
}

printf "%d values read from '%s'\n" ${#arr[@]} "$1"
declare -p arr
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using with your file `test.js`, you would receive:

```
$ bash readfile.sh test.js
3 values read from 'test.js'
declare -a arr='([0]="X_CLOUD_ID" [1]="100" [2]="no")'
```

(**note:** `declare -p` was simply used to dump the contents of the array)

You can use `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]` any way you like within your program. Repetitively asking for a filename is left to you. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

(**also note:** `bash` and POSIX `sh` are not at all the same thing. You have no arrays and no `readarray` or `mapfile` with POSIX shell. Please remove one of the tags from your question. Your `#!/usr/bin/env bash` specifies `bash`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the approach @David